# Animating a svg, with a mask, I am having trouble clipping outside of the svg

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I have a simple svg with two grouped paths that is a shape of a tshirt. I have created a mask with a circle with the fill color red, I am animating that mask into from the bottom of one path to the top. You can see it running on codepen. The part where I am stuck is how do I clip everything outside the tshirt with a stroke so you can only see the masked path animate inside.

thanks ahead of time

here is the code pen https://codepen.io/wispyco/pen/abvweMp

```css
#svg {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

circle {
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-name: tower;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes tower {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg aria-labelledby="title" id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g stroke="black" fill="none">
          <path d="M96.6 37.3l-10.5 9.2c-1.1 1-2.9.8-3.8-.4L76.5 38l-1.4 50.1c0 1.4-1.2 2.5-2.6 2.5H27.4c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.6-2.5L23.4 38l-5.8 8c-.9 1.2-2.6 1.4-3.8.4L3.4 37.3c-1-.9-1.2-2.5-.3-3.5L18 15.3c2.9-3.7 7.4-5.8 12.1-5.8h7c.8 0 1.5.5 1.9 1.2 2.4 4.8 5.6 8 11.5 8s9.1-3.2 11.5-8c.4-.7 1.1-1.2 1.9-1.2h6.2c4.7 0 9.2 2.1 12.2 5.8l14.9 18.5c.6 1 .5 2.6-.6 3.5z"/>
        </g>
        <mask id="myMask">
        <g fill="red">
          <path d="M96.6 37.3l-10.5 9.2c-1.1 1-2.9.8-3.8-.4L76.5 38l-1.4 50.1c0 1.4-1.2 2.5-2.6 2.5H27.4c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.6-2.5L23.4 38l-5.8 8c-.9 1.2-2.6 1.4-3.8.4L3.4 37.3c-1-.9-1.2-2.5-.3-3.5L18 15.3c2.9-3.7 7.4-5.8 12.1-5.8h7c.8 0 1.5.5 1.9 1.2 2.4 4.8 5.6 8 11.5 8s9.1-3.2 11.5-8c.4-.7 1.1-1.2 1.9-1.2h6.2c4.7 0 9.2 2.1 12.2 5.8l14.9 18.5c.6 1 .5 2.6-.6 3.5z"/>
        </g>
        </mask>
         <circle fill="red" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" mask="url(#myMask)" />

    </svg>
```

Comment: typically if you want to clip something you'd use a clip-path.

Comment: Move the circle in the group and clip the group. Also you can simplify your code by giving the path an `id` and use it in the mask instead of repeating the same path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is CSS solution where I will consider mask. I will be using the path version with fill and without stroke as mask and the path version with stroke and no fill as background:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  -webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M96.6 37.3l-10.5 9.2c-1.1 1-2.9.8-3.8-.4L76.5 38l-1.4 50.1c0 1.4-1.2 2.5-2.6 2.5H27.4c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.6-2.5L23.4 38l-5.8 8c-.9 1.2-2.6 1.4-3.8.4L3.4 37.3c-1-.9-1.2-2.5-.3-3.5L18 15.3c2.9-3.7 7.4-5.8 12.1-5.8h7c.8 0 1.5.5 1.9 1.2 2.4 4.8 5.6 8 11.5 8s9.1-3.2 11.5-8c.4-.7 1.1-1.2 1.9-1.2h6.2c4.7 0 9.2 2.1 12.2 5.8l14.9 18.5c.6 1 .5 2.6-.6 3.5z"/></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
          mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M96.6 37.3l-10.5 9.2c-1.1 1-2.9.8-3.8-.4L76.5 38l-1.4 50.1c0 1.4-1.2 2.5-2.6 2.5H27.4c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.6-2.5L23.4 38l-5.8 8c-.9 1.2-2.6 1.4-3.8.4L3.4 37.3c-1-.9-1.2-2.5-.3-3.5L18 15.3c2.9-3.7 7.4-5.8 12.1-5.8h7c.8 0 1.5.5 1.9 1.2 2.4 4.8 5.6 8 11.5 8s9.1-3.2 11.5-8c.4-.7 1.1-1.2 1.9-1.2h6.2c4.7 0 9.2 2.1 12.2 5.8l14.9 18.5c.6 1 .5 2.6-.6 3.5z"/></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  -webkit-mask:inherit;
          mask:inherit;
}
.box::before {
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
  animation:move 3s infinite linear alternate;
}
.box::after {
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" d="M96.6 37.3l-10.5 9.2c-1.1 1-2.9.8-3.8-.4L76.5 38l-1.4 50.1c0 1.4-1.2 2.5-2.6 2.5H27.4c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.6-2.5L23.4 38l-5.8 8c-.9 1.2-2.6 1.4-3.8.4L3.4 37.3c-1-.9-1.2-2.5-.3-3.5L18 15.3c2.9-3.7 7.4-5.8 12.1-5.8h7c.8 0 1.5.5 1.9 1.2 2.4 4.8 5.6 8 11.5 8s9.1-3.2 11.5-8c.4-.7 1.1-1.2 1.9-1.2h6.2c4.7 0 9.2 2.1 12.2 5.8l14.9 18.5c.6 1 .5 2.6-.6 3.5z"/></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform:translateY(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```