# How fill png image with css

Tags: html, css

I need to fill the picture with color inside but not outside with css

We have png

[image]

What I do

```css
img {
  background:#8abfbe;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze88p.png">
```

What I need

[image]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61494422/8620333

Comment: Unless you use some image manipulation library (javascript), I don't think this is possible. PNG (or most other image formats) only have data to display the image, not understand whats in it. It may be easier if you have an svg, which you may be able to set a fill color, though I'm not sure about a pure CSS solution. Look into css "filter" property which you may be able to abuse.

Comment: [link](https://redstapler.co/change-image-color-pure-css/) Try this tutorial

Comment: @LuboMasura no, i have colors array, and with js I want set color for each tshirt, but I can't use svg(((  this is the condition of the competition in which I participate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use your first PNG and make only the outside transparent then you can use that image as mask and also as a background to consider the black lines:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/F5n9N7c/shirt.png) center/contain no-repeat;
          mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/F5n9N7c/shirt.png) center/contain no-repeat;
  
  background:url(https://i.ibb.co/F5n9N7c/shirt.png) center/contain no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode:darken;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-color:lightblue;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:red;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:lightgreen;"></div>
```

Here is the image used to better understand:

```css
img {
  background:red;
  width:150px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/F5n9N7c/shirt.png">
```

---

An optimized version using CSS variables:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  
  --m:url(https://i.ibb.co/F5n9N7c/shirt.png) center/contain no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask:var(--m);
          mask:var(--m);
  
  background:var(--m) var(--c,transparent);
  background-blend-mode:darken;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--c:lightblue;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--c:red;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--c:lightgreen;"></div>
```